# MongoDb get position of an item in the collection with sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I use a table with sorting and pagination.
To get data I use find with sort, skip, limit, to get data for the current page of the table.

Question: When I add a new item to the collection, I need to open the page in the table. 
That is, I need to get the position of the item in the collection, taking into account the sorting.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Can you explain why you need that? Because I don't see a point for that. Might be you trying to solve your problem in wrong way.

Comment: I have a table with sorting and pagination. 
The table is sorted by user name (for example). 
The first 10 results are displayed.
I added a new user, and considering sorting by name, new user will be in the collection on the 23rd place (for example),
that is on the 3rd page of the table.
I need to get the position of new user, to open the desired page.